# Prediction Using Linear Regression

Tags: statistics, regression, variance

[image]

I believe I know what formula to use; I just don't know what I'm missing for the X variables.

I believe the relevant formulas are:

$$s_f^2 = s^2\bigg{[}1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(X-\bar{X})^2}{(n-1)(s_x^2)}\bigg{]}$$

where

$$s^2 = .1265^2 = .0160023$$
$$n = 62$$

and 
$$\hat{Y} \pm t_cs_f$$

where

$$t_c = 2.915$$
&
$$\hat{Y} = 1.2130$$

If this is all correct, I just need to figure out the X terms in the first formula. I can't seem to work out how that's possible with the given information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slope coefficient is $\hat{\beta}_1$ in $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X $, so its $99\%$ CI is 
$$
\left( 1.21 - 0.1265t_{0.995}(60), 1.21 + 0.1265t_{0.995}(60) \right)
$$

Comment: How did you arrive at 50 for $s_f$?

Comment: Misspelled, sorry. This is the given s.d. in the question. Anyway, your calculations are for the CI of the predicted values, while the required was the CI for the $\hat{\beta}_1$.

Comment: No need to apologize. I very much appreciate your help. What value is supposed to be in place of the 50? I'm not following how you derived this formula.

Comment: $ 62 - 2 = 60$, the df of the $t$